# Could not load file or assembly. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context

Tags: c#, nuget

I've got a solutionA that references a custom nuget package - LogisticsPlatform.Model.Component.CustomerOrder v1.0.16.0.

I've updated the CustomerOrder solution by adding a new class to it. I've modified the package version to 1.0.17.0 and published it to the nuget feed.

When updating the nuget in solutionA, solutionA builds but when running it, it fails on startup with the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'LogisticsPlatform.Model.Component.CustomerOrder, Version=1.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
File name: 'LogisticsPlatform.Model.Component.CustomerOrder, Version=1.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
```

I get a similar error when running unit tests.

I've tried a clean/rebuild.

Any suggestions on the cause of the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Perhaps you should run more tests in your nuget package.

Comment: @McNets The nuget package is just a class library and I've just tested the original class and the new one and they both pass as expected.